# How to do closest guess on C99, C11 or C17?

Tags: c, gcc, c99, c11, c17

I have a source code of C-project that has more than 600 c-files in it and it compiles for ARM mcu using GCC toolchain. I wonder how can I make a closest guess about which of the C standard this c-project is compliant to among C99, C11 and C17?

Comment: Start with `-std=c89` as arguments for GCC and work your way up until it successfully builds. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html

Comment: What compiler options were used for GCC when compiling for ARM? Look for `-std=xx`

Comment: Chances are, the code uses GNU extensions, so it's not actually any of those. So try adding `-pedantic` to compiler options.

Comment: Also, if the code is not initially warning free, you are going to have a bad time with it, most likely.

Comment: Guessing is not an appropriate technique for software development.

Comment: 600 c files and no documentation or hints of how to build it? Then abandon this project as early on as possible...